# Minimum number of samples outside interval, unknown distribution

Tags: probability-inequalities

I'm considering a graph that shows the mean of $n$ samples drawn from an unknown, continuous population. It also shows the standard error of the means.

From this I calculated the standard deviation $\sigma$ of the samples: $$\sigma = SEM \sqrt n$$

I would like to know at least how many of the values in the sample lie outside a certain interval around the mean: $n \cdot P(X < a \lor b < X)$, with $a<\mu<b$.

If X were normal distributed, I would just put `42 * P(X<1 or 5<X) for X normal with mu=4, sigma=2` in wolframalpha. However, it is not. Can I still calculate some lower bound?

Comment: What is your definition of SEM? Can you use Chebyshev's inequality?

Comment: Hi @soakley, for SEM I used $SEM = s : \sqrt n$ with $s$ being the sample standard deviation, $n$ the sample size. Though I do not know what definition was used when the graph was created. $n$ was 30 so I thought $s$ is quite similar to the real $\sigma$ -- My understanding is that Chebyshev requires a probability parameter, which is lower than 100% (unlike in the case of normal distribution). I guess there is no way around that?

Comment: There is no lower bound - you could have no observations beyond 2 stdev from the mean, for example. A version of Samuelson's inequality could be used to give an upper bound.

Comment: You're right, I see. Pathological cases include everything being 1 stdev away from the mean, or everything equaling the mean except for a single drastic outlier. So only if the $a$ or $b$ ranges are very close to $\mu$ can we derive anything.

Comment: (I suppose a summary of what was discussed in the comments would be a valid answer to the question to accept)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sample-based inequality from Kaban (see Wikipedia article on Chebyshev's Inequality, Finite Samples section) is $$P \left( |X - \bar{x} | \ge ks \right) \le \frac{1}{n+1} \left\lfloor  \frac{n+1}{n} \left( \frac{n-1}{k^2} + 1 \right) \right\rfloor,$$ where $n$ is the sample size and $s$ is the sample standard deviation (assumed to be using $n-1$ in the denominator).

For $n=42$ and $k=2$, we get $$P \left( |X - \bar{x} | \ge 2s \right) \le \frac{1}{43} \left\lfloor  \frac{43}{42} \left( \frac{41}{4} + 1 \right) \right\rfloor = \frac{11}{43}=0.2558,$$ which isn't that far off from the usual bound using the traditional Chebyshev inequality.